# An error occurred deploying Cordova plugins. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.plugins.AndroidPluginDeployer)

Tags: cordova, oracle-maf

[image]
I am trying to deploy simple maf application on my device or emulator,
but it gives corodova plugin error.This error are after updating maf plugin in jdeveloper,and I can't figure out from last 3 days. How can I resolve this issue?
I have java /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_73/jre/bin/java at this location on system and when I see in jdeveloper project libraries it has taken following configuration of java as follows /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/jdk/jre/bin/java

```
[11:09:10 AM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[11:09:10 AM] Target platform is  (Android).
[11:09:10 AM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "CRUDDemo" to Android using profile "Android1".
[11:09:10 AM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[11:09:13 AM] Started Android Debug Bridge server.
[11:09:13 AM] Verifying a single Android device is online and connected to the ADB server...
[11:09:13 AM] Unable to obtain the version of ARM supported by the Android device.  The application may not work correctly if the device does not support at least ARMv6.
[11:09:13 AM] Running dependency analysis...
[11:09:13 AM] Building...
[11:09:16 AM] Deploying 3 profiles...
[11:09:16 AM] Verifying project is a MAF project...
[11:09:16 AM] Wrote Archive Module to /home/yogesh/jdeveloper/mywork/PublicSamples/CRUDDemo/ViewController/deploy/ViewController_MobileFeatureArchive1.jar
[11:09:16 AM] Verifying project is a MAF project...
[11:09:16 AM] Wrote Archive Module to /home/yogesh/jdeveloper/mywork/PublicSamples/CRUDDemo/ApplicationController/deploy/ApplicationController_MobileFeatureArchive1.jar
[11:09:16 AM] Starting to prepare the packaging...
[11:09:17 AM] Copying FARs to the MAF application...
[11:09:17 AM] Extracting Feature Archive file, "ApplicationController_MobileFeatureArchive1.jar" to deployment folder, "ApplicationController".
[11:09:17 AM] Extracting Feature Archive file, "ViewController_MobileFeatureArchive1.jar" to deployment folder, "ViewController".
[11:09:17 AM] Copying framework java resource files...
[11:09:17 AM] Copying common javascript files...
[11:09:17 AM] Copying application image files...
[11:09:17 AM] Copying .adf files...
[11:09:17 AM] Copying security related files to the MAF application...
[11:09:20 AM] Creating Android preferences XML files...
[11:09:20 AM] Replacing tokens in file AndroidManifest.xml ...
[11:09:20 AM] Copying adfmf-manifest.properties file...
[11:09:20 AM] Deploying Cordova Plugins...
[11:09:22 AM] Command-line executed: [/home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/jdk/bin/java, -jar, /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/maf-helper.jar, deploy, -config, /home/yogesh/jdeveloper/mywork/PublicSamples/CRUDDemo/deploy/Android1/config.json]
[11:09:22 AM] Error Code : INTERNAL_ERROR
[11:09:22 AM] module.js:339
[11:09:22 AM] throw err;
[11:09:22 AM] ^
[11:09:22 AM] 
[11:09:22 AM] Error: Cannot find module '/home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/plugman/node_modules/.bin/plugman'
[11:09:22 AM] at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
[11:09:22 AM] at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
[11:09:22 AM] at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
[11:09:22 AM] at startup (node.js:134:18)
[11:09:22 AM] at node.js:961:3
[11:09:22 AM] oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[11:09:22 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.runProcess(Unknown Source)
[11:09:22 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.executeCmd(Unknown Source)
[11:09:22 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.addPlugin(Unknown Source)
[11:09:22 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.deploy(Unknown Source)
[11:09:22 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.MafHelperMain.main(Unknown Source)
[11:09:22 AM] Caused by: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[11:09:22 AM] ... 5 more
[11:09:22 AM] Caused by: java.lang.Exception
[11:09:22 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException.<init>(Unknown SoM] ... 5 more
[11:09:22 AM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[11:09:22 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[11:09:22 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[11:09:22 AM] An error occurred deploying Cordova plugins. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.plugins.AndroidPluginDeployer)
M] ... 5 more
[11:09:22 AM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[11:09:22 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[11:09:22 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[11:09:22 AM] An error occurred deploying Cordova plugins. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.plugins.AndroidPluginDeployer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i updated maf so something happened with curodova so i removed rm -rf node_modules directory which is located at/home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/plugman/node_modules

and the apt-get install npm in ubantu and then i go to

/home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools directory and extracted the plugman and then start deploying works for me